# Setup operators on Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was wondering how I can change my game difficulty and how to change my game to creative. Every time I type in `/gamemode 1` or `/gamemode creative` it comes up with:

> I am sorry but you do not have permission to perform this command.
>   Please contact the server administrators if you believe that this is
>   an error.

I thought this was weird because I am the server administrator.

Comment: You are the admin, but you are not an Op (operator) on your server.  You need access either to the Minecraft server console or a shell on the server so that you can add your username to the `ops.txt` file (at least I think that's what it's called).

Comment: Nope had no idea about that post :P

Comment: What version of Minecraft is this?

Comment: 1.7.4 my minecraft automatically updates.

Answer (score 6):

You need to configure your Minecraft server.  From the [Minecraft wiki:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server)

> #Configuring the Minecraft server
>
> 1. Configure the server by editing the `server.properties` file, the
>    format for which is explained here. Be certain to edit the file with
>    a text editor that does not add formatting (e.g., for italics).
>    Additional configuration may not be necessary as many servers run
>    fine from the default values.
> 2. Add your username to the `admin.txt` and/or `ops.txt` (newer Minecraft
>    versions may not have an `admin.txt` file). `Ops.txt` and `admin.txt`
>    determine who may execute server commands. In other words, operator
>    ("op") privileges allow you to control certain aspects of the game
>    (e.g., teleporting players). Op privileges may also be granted from
>    the server GUI: type "op " and it will automatically add
>     to the `ops.txt` file.

Comment: Tried doing that already than I retried it and also restarted the server. Still not the result I wanted.

Comment: @Madz Have you tried going into your server command line and entered `/op <playername>`?

Comment: Yep already tried that. Came up with the same thing.